# df -h showing weird output

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, df

I am getting a weird output on `df -h` for one of the partitions. Here is the output:

```
/var/sdc$ df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       990M  569M  354M  62% /
/dev/sda2       976M  285M  640M  31% /var
/dev/sdc        5.0Z  5.0Z     0 100% /var/sdc
```

what does `Z` mean in `5.0Z` and how can I free up the space there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the unit of `ZiB` (or simply `Z`).

1 ZiB = 2^70 Bytes

So as you have 5.0Z, multiply it by `5` to get your FS size.

From `info df`:

```
`Z'
`ZiB'
     2^70 = 1,180,591,620,717,411,303,424.
```

Note that, `ZB` is generally called ZettaBytes (10^21 = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000), but `ZiB` is not given any particular name.

But if we follow the trend, e.g. `KB` for KiloBytes, whereas `KiB` is called KibiBytes, similarly this can be named something like ZettiBytes? Again nothing official AFAIK.

---

**Regarding the weird filesystem size:**

Check the entry carefully:

```
/dev/sdc        5.0Z  5.0Z     0 100% /var/sdc
```

you have created filesystem on the whole disk `/dev/sdc`, not on any partition of it (e.g. `/dev/sdc1`, have you created any?), leading to this weirdness. Unmount the filesystem, create necessary partition(s) on the disk, and mount the partition(s) (e.g. could be `/dev/sdc1`) accordingly to meet your need.

Comment: is there any way to free up this space. The partition was of 50 GB size . I am new to this and not sure how to free up this space. I can see no file is created on this filesystem

Comment: @user3034987 Are yo sure? If so, then it seems pretty weird. Also that much space seems weird too to me at least. To free up space remove unnecessary files from `/var/sdc`, also i see `df` is showing it as `00% used. Is this a local device?

Comment: yes its a local device and surprisingly there isn't any files on /var/sdc here is the output ubuntu@UbuntuSource-v2:/mnt$ ls -lah /var/sdc
total 0

Comment: @user3034987 Hmmm. Whats the output of `du -sh /var/sdc`. Also whats the filesystem?

Comment: here is the output ubuntu@UbuntuSource-v2:/mnt$ du -sh /var/sdc
4.0K /var/sdc and its an ext4 filesystem

Comment: @user3034987 Check my edits.

Comment: I am getting an issue after unmount /dev/sdc. I created 3 partitions using fdisk but its showing some error while creating the filesystem :                             ubuntu@UbuntuSource-v2:/mnt$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
sudo: unable to resolve host UbuntuSource-v2
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Could not stat /dev/sdc1 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?

Comment: @user3034987 What i used is an example. Presumably you have not created any partition, check the output of `ls /dev/sdc*`. Also if you have any further query regarding partitioning, or filesystem creation, please ask a new question as that is quite different from the initial question.